# Why do my two cats use one litter box for pooping and the other for peeing?

Tags: cats, behavior, toilet-training, multi-pet-families

I had two cats, and I was wondering as to why they use one litterbox for only pooping while use the other for only peeing?

They used to poop in the litterbox A (both) and pee in litterbox B (also both) and rarely switch litterbox uses. You see in this case I'm talking about TWO cats who I guess copy each other not just one.

I took them both to the vet and they were fine, nothing wrong with them. I just wanted to know why they do that, if anyone has a hint then please comment.

Comment: I think we'd all be guessing at what's going on in a cat's mind. We can justify the advantages of burying feces when we remember that because of their size cats are both predator and prey, and we can consider urine scent marking as communication, which might explain it... but odds are that a cat doesn't think it through in those terms and just does it because it seems the right thing to do. (Heck, there's a lot of stuff we apes do because it's instinctive and then explain to ourselves later.) For mine I think it's more a matter of which box is convenient and at what times they eat/drink.

Answer (score 6):

Wild guess --  the boxes are side by side? My friend had the same situation as you do. One day she sent me an unrelated photo, and I saw her litter boxes side by side. Cats view side by side boxes as one big box. Makes sense to use one side for poop and the other for pee. It's what I would do.

Comment: Well, they were side by side at the start so good guess, but at the time only one cat used to display this behaviour, and the other used only one to do it's business (poop and pee). They had some problems over the litterboxes, so I seperated them (the boxes) and after that the other cat too started to display this behaviour. It peed in the box the other peed in and pooped in the one the other pooped in.

Comment: Well, I'd consider myself lucky and take advantage of this if I were you. I'd put more absorbent/clumping and nicer smelling litter in the pee box, and more easily diggable and shovelable litter in the poo box.

Answer (score 0):

My two girls do this because of hygiene reasons, which I find very unique and amazing. They will have a system where Litter Box A is for peeing and Litter Box B is for pooping, they are very strict about this. However every two weeks they actually switch it up and use Box B for peeing and Box A for pooping. Cats are very intelligent and hygienic creatures. My girls have a regimen of keeping clean and also expect me to keep their boxes clean every single day lol. Your cats may be the same as mine! Just some very clean cats (: quick little edit, I also keep my boxes in separate corners in case you do as well.